# Build not performed for all projects in release of multi-module Maven projects

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm having an issue with build during release of multi-module Maven projects. I have this structure:

```
parent
|-- potato
|-- lettuce
|-- raddish
```

and I want to release projects potato and lettuce. (They have no dependency on snapshot raddish.)

The command I used was:

```
mvn release:prepare -pl potato,lettuce ... (tag, versions and so on) -DpushChanges=false
```

and every commit in the history was as I expected -- one commit changing version of both potato and lettuce from X-SNAPSHOT to X and one changing X to Y-SNAPSHOT. There was one tag created for both projects.

However, there are two build phases during release:prepare -- one calling verify on the X version and one calling verify on the Y-SNAPSHOT version. Both phases builded only the first project, not the second one. (First specified in the -pl argument.) Same happends when calling release:perform. Only the first project is being deployed, everything else is ignored.

The prepare phase generated release.properties file similar to this (note the exec.pomFileName=potato/pom.xml):

```
project.scm.release.test\:potato.developerConnection=scm\:git\:http\://localhost\:3000/petr/release-test.git
project.scm.release.test\:lettuce.connection=scm\:git\:http\://localhost\:3000/petr/release-test.git
scm.commentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin]
project.scm.release.test\:potato.connection=scm\:git\:http\://localhost\:3000/petr/release-test.git
exec.pomFileName=potato/pom.xml
pushChanges=false
releaseStrategyId=default
project.scm.release.test\:lettuce.developerConnection=scm\:git\:http\://localhost\:3000/petr/release-test.git
scm.tag=33
project.scm.release.test\:lettuce.tag=HEAD
remoteTagging=true
scm.branchCommitComment=@{prefix} prepare branch @{releaseLabel}
projectVersionPolicyId=default
scm.url=scm\:git\:http\://localhost\:3000/petr/release-test.git
scm.tagNameFormat=@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}
project.scm.release.test\:lettuce.url=http\://localhost\:3000/petr/release-test.git
pinExternals=false
project.scm.release.test\:potato.tag=HEAD
preparationGoals=clean verify
scm.releaseCommitComment=@{prefix} prepare release @{releaseLabel}
exec.snapshotReleasePluginAllowed=false
exec.additionalArguments=-pl=lettuce,potato
project.rel.release.test\:potato=33
project.rel.release.test\:lettuce=33
project.scm.release.test\:potato.url=http\://localhost\:3000/petr/release-test.git
scm.developmentCommitComment=@{prefix} prepare for next development iteration
scm.rollbackCommitComment=@{prefix} rollback the release of @{releaseLabel}
completedPhase=end-release
```

Is there a way to release both projects using just one tag and commit but build both potato and lettuce (but not raddish)?

I'm using Release plugin 3.0.0-M1.

Comment: How should it work? The plugin is expected to do a single commit in a git repository, produce a single tag, but release 2 subprojects independently? I'm guessing your use case is unsupported, because it's quite untypical. Multi-module project is a single entity, and it should be released as the whole.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Yes, the plugin should create a single commit and create a single tag but update just the specified projects. And it does exactly that if -pl is specified. But I also want it to build everything specified in the project list.

Comment: A multi module setup but using it as a separate independent modules sounds like either your setup is wrong or you should really go with a multi module setup and use it as it...that will make release process easy....